# Build a graph with the biggest distance (edges) between two nodes is equal than two

Tags: python, algorithm

I have to build an algorithm using Python:

1. This algorithm has to build a graph that has the minimum possible number of edges given a number `n` of nodes.
2. we have to go from one node to another node using at most two edges.
3. some nodes cannot be adjacent to each other.
4. it is guaranteed that for a given input we will be able to find a solution that satisfies the three items above.

The function signature can be `createGraph(n: int,forbidenEdge: list[int]) -> list[int]`

One example: `n = 4`, `forbidenEdge = [[1,3]]`

The function returns the edges that have to be built so we have a minimum number of edges in the graph.

For the given example we have this possible output (sometimes we can have more than one output): `[[1, 2],[4, 2],[2, 3]]`

I am not sure if the solution I am thinking to implement is correct.

If we do not have any restrictions or if there is at least a node that can be connected to any node the minimum number of edges is equal to (n - 1). We can choose a node that can connect to all the other nodes. The problem is when no node can connect to all the other nodes. For this, I am thinking to create the following algorithm, but I am not sure if it is correct. For this situation I am thinking about the following algorithm:

We have to check the number of connections that each node can do and order them in a list according to this number. We have to check if the nodes that cannot connect to the node center are able to be connected to all other nodes (if it is possible, we connect the nodes that can be connected to the node center and the other nodes we connect to each other ... we print the connections) if it is not possible we have to choose another node center, the next in the sorted list. We repeat it until we find a node center that when chosen is going be possible to build edges between the nodes in a way that from any node we can move to another node passing through two edges only.

For this algorithm, if we have `n = 4`, `forbidenEdge = [[1,3],[2,4]]` ... node 3 can be the node center. Node 1 cannot connect to the node center, so it connects to all the other nodes. So we have the output: `[[1,2],[1,4],[2,3],[3,4]]`.

Is this algorithm going to get it right for any `n` and any `forbidenEdge` list? How could I prove it?

Comment: Have you tried implementing it? If not, try it! If so, what happened? Running code on different test cases is usually a way to verify whether or not an algorithm works. If this is for competitive programming, the problem prompt usually has test cases you can run your algorithm against, and it'll tell you if you get any wrong.

Comment: There is only one test case. I am implementing it. I  have to create the test cases, so I have to know if the logic I wrote above is right even to check if the algorithm I will create is correct.

Comment: IOW, given a graph (V, E) of diameter at most 2, we want to find the smallest subset E' of E such that the graph (V, E') has diameter at most 2. Seems hard. Do you have an online judge link?

Comment: Directed or undirected graph?

Comment: 1. definitely sounds like you would need to use path compression here.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `list[list[int]]` instead of `list[int]`? (And `forbiddenEdge` instead of `forbidenEdge`, I don't see what Joe has to do with this :-)

Comment: What do you mean with "node center"? I know a definition for center of a graph, but that's not something you can "choose" and it's generally not a single node.

Comment: He means a node that connects to all/most of the other nodes. It does in that way facilitate connections between the nodes that are directly connected to it by working as a central hub. In the trivial case you are able to choose a node as "node center" that can connect to all the other nodes, then your graph looks like a star with the chosen node center in the middle.

Comment: Tried LP method, like min $\sum_{i,j} E_{i,j}$ where $(i,j) \in\ $ Nodes? Constraints could be $\sum_{i,v} E_{i,v}+E_{v,j} \ge 2 \ \forall i,v,j \in\ $Nodes

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** You can calculate the Number of two-edge jumps from the dot-product of the connectivity-matrix with itself. The number of one-edge jumps is just the connectivity-matrix.

---

**Not the solution**, but some considerations, that I hope are still helpful for your search of one:

Consider you have a connectivity-matrix (one column and row for each node, and a `1` if there is an edge between the nodes and `0` if not). For example for forbidden edges `[[1, 2], [3, 4]` and `n = 4` the connectivity-matrix would look like this:

```
[
    [0, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0]
]
```

Then you already know the number of one-edge jumps between two nodes, by the connectivity-matrix itself (so far so trivial). But more interesting you can calculate the number of two-edge jumps between two nodes by the dot-product of the connectivity-matrix with itself! The idea is, that the dot-product basically counts the common neighbors between two nodes.

The goal is basically now, to remove edges (set the numbers to zero in the connectivity-matrix) until none can't be removed anymore. An algorithm could look like this:

1. Initialize your connectivity-matrix `cm` with the diagonal as `0` (a node never connects directly to itself, even if that would be allowed, the edge would be pruned when the goal is least number of edges, because it doesn't add any useful connections to the graph).
2. Set all the node-pairs of the forbidden-edges to `0` in the connectivity-matrix.
3. Calculate the number of two-edge jumps (`numpy.dot(cm, cm)`).
4. Calculate the total number of paths between nodes by adding the one-edge jumps (the connectivity-matrix) and the two-edge jumps (calculated in step 3).
5. If any number in the calculated matrix from step 4 is 0, then the connectivity matrix is invalid, either the problem is unsolvable if this happens in the first iteration, or the last removed edge invalidated the connectivity matrix (shouldn't happen if implemented correctly).
6. Now comes the hard part, choose a node-pair to remove from the connectivity-matrix and repeat steps 3-6, until no more edges can be removed.

For step 6 I have some ideas, that can be implemented by filtering on the numpy-array.

1. Obviously you can only remove edges where there is an edge to begin with (1 in the connectivity matrix).
2. You can only remove edges, where the matrix calculated in 4 is at least 2. Or else you would remove the last connection.
3. You can't remove edges, where it is the last connection of a two-edge jump for a node-pair that is not directly connected. I haven't yet found something direct to check that.

So this unfortunately doesn't solve your problem, but maybe you or someone else can build on or get inspired by it. There possibly are more mathematical principles that can be harnessed like calculating the number of two-step jumps from the dot-product. In combination then with a fast numpy-implementation a smart brute-force approach could be possible (depending on the maximum number of nodes of course).

Comment: At best, this is a step towards another algorithm. But another algorithm isn't even what the question is about. They already have an algorithm, and the question is whether it's correct and how to prove it. I don't see how this answer is supposed to be useful for that at all.

Comment: **You are right**, it does not answer the question of if and how the algorithm can be proven to be correct. But one could argue, that the underlying question is how to solve the graph-problem, and proving Alucards algorithm is only one way of doing that. I posted my answer, because I came to some (at least for me) interesting conclusions. I thought those conclusions could be interesting to Alucard and others as well even though they don't directly relate to the exact question asked. I'm sorry if I was mistaken in that assumption.